# Как исключить файл из проверки при построении проекта?

Tags: java, eclipse

Есть проект из .java файлов. Среди них есть один, который я не хочу, чтобы входил в сборку, но я хочу, чтобы он у меня находился в package. В нём могут быть ошибки и поэтому проект не хочет строиться **Build project**, пока я его не удалю/исправлю/закоментирую. На него другие файлы (т.е. классы) не ссылаются.

Как его оставить в проекте с подсветкой синтаксиса, и ошибками, но при этом, чтобы проект строился спокойно не обращая на файл внимания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правой кнопкой щёлкните файл, выберите Build Path / Exclude... Если я правильно понял что нужно.